# Lower level implementation of solidity call

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, ethereum-classic

How is call() implemented at lower level in Ethereum Solidity compiler? Most of the places it is written that it is used to send message to contracts. But I need to know syntax and semantics of call() implementation at compiler level.